# SimpleDateFormat java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm hopeless trying to parse a String to a Date but its not working. Could not be that hard? I'm doing it like this description: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
String timestamp = "05 MAY 2017 15:20:26 UTC";   
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
Date date = sdf.parse(timestamp);
```

But I'm still getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "05 MAY 2017 15:20:26 UTC"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at GetTime.main(GetTime.java:18)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your default locale?

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  The suggestions that the problem may arise from a locale issue seem plausible.

Comment: For me it results in `Fri May 05 23:20:26 AWST 2017`; No exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Locale` in your `SimpleDateFormat` for example :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.UK);
```

Comment: thx, that was the missing puzzle! :)

Comment: you are welcome @EroStefano